# This object does not have an attribute named "subnetName"

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create Azure virtual network ( azurerm_virtual_network ) and Subnets based on the input json local block.

```
locals {
  networks = {
    hub-vnet = {
      address_space = ["10.0.0.0/9"]
      subnets = {
        app = {
          address_prefix    = ["10.1.0.0./16"]
          enable_netgateway = false
        },
        db = {
          address_prefix    = ["10.2.0.0./16"]
          enable_netgateway = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

locals {
  vnet_details = flatten([
    for k, v in local.networks : {
      // Nested for loop to read the map in values
      for snet_k, snet_val in v.subnets :
      snet_k => merge(
        {
          vnetName         = k
          vnet_addresspace = v.address_space
          subnetName       = snet_k
        }, snet_val
      )
      // Filtering 
      if(snet_val.enable_netgateway == true)
    }
  ])
}




resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  for_each = { for item in local.vnet_details : item.subnetName => item }

  name                = each.value.vnetName
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = each.value.vnet_addresspace
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = { for item in local.vnet_details : item.subnetName => item }

  name                 = each.value.subnetName
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example[each.key].name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefix
}
```

Expectation is create app subnet but I am getting below error. Could someone help me what is missing the foreach loop in azurerm_virtual_network resource ?

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on forloop.tf line 89, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example":
│   89:   for_each = { for item in local.vnet_details : item.subnetName => item }
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "subnetName".
```

Comment: please include the subnet module configuration in the query @Madhumitha

Comment: @VinayB I have isolated the vnet and subnet resources and updated the question.

Comment: is this the configuration you're expecting ![link](https://i.imgur.com/NlwF77y.png) @Madhumitha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Verifying Azure Virtual Network and Subnet Configurations in the Azure Portal

The reason for the error is that your `for_each` expression in the `azurerm_virtual_network` resource is not structured properly. In particular, the `local.vnet_details` list that you're looping over does not have a `subnetName` attribute for each element, since the `vnet_details` list that you've created has a flattened structure that does not correspond to what the `for_each` expects.

The main focus of my configuration will be to create a configuration that correctly defines and uses `local.vnet_details` for creating virtual networks and `local.subnet_details` for creating subnets.

**My configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

locals {
  networks = {
    "hub-vnet" = {
      address_space = ["10.0.0.0/9"],
      subnets = {
        app = {
          address_prefixes = ["10.1.0.0/16"], // Ensure this is a list
          enable_netgateway = false
        },
        db = {
          address_prefixes = ["10.2.0.0/16"], // Ensure this is a list
          enable_netgateway = true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

locals {
  vnet_details = { for vnet_name, vnet_config in local.networks :
                   vnet_name => {
                     address_space = vnet_config.address_space,
                     subnets = vnet_config.subnets
                   }
                 }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "testvkrg-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  for_each = local.vnet_details

  name                = each.key
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
}


locals {
  // Flatten subnets into a structure suitable for iteration in resource blocks
  subnet_details = merge([
    for vnet_name, vnet_config in local.networks : {
      for subnet_name, subnet_config in vnet_config.subnets : "${vnet_name}-${subnet_name}" => {
        vnet_name      = vnet_name,
        subnet_name    = subnet_name,
        address_prefixes = subnet_config.address_prefixes // Ensure this matches the structure
      }
    }
  ]...)
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  for_each             = local.subnet_details
  name                 = each.value.subnet_name
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = each.value.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes

  # Explicitly declare the dependency on the virtual network
  depends_on = [azurerm_virtual_network.example]
}
```

***Deployment Succeded:***

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The trailing dots on these lines could be the problem:

address_prefix    = ["10.1.0.0./16"]

address_prefix    = ["10.2.0.0./16"]